# BPXBATCH utility in z/OS - executing a jar file

Tags: java, unix, mainframe, zos, jcl

i want to invoke a jar file from MF and then read and copy the data in Mf datasets.
BPXBATCH utility can help to achieve this through OMVS, how can i login in MF unix server, i tried giving OMVS but not able to achieve

Also can someone give a detail explanation of STD ENV step classpath and PARM which is used in this utility.

Also is there any other way than invoking a shell.

Comment: You seem to have several questions that are mostly related to using your system or a specific software, not related to programming. Such questions may fit better on https://superuser.com/. You should ask separate single questions and add enough details and background information to allow someone to answer.

Comment: Please add more details about: How do you try to login? What is the JCL you try to run? We cannot possibly answer your questions when you don't care to show details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to log in to USS, you will need an OMVS segment in your RACF profile. Here is an example of a REXX that creates the correct type of RACF profile with an OMVS segment:

```
"ADDUSER ("tso_userid")",
          "TSO(ACCT(ACCT#) PROC("logon_proc") SIZE(8000))",
          "DFLTGRP(IDZUSERS)",
          "OMVS(HOME('/u/"uss_userid"') PROG('/bin/sh') AUTOUID)"
```

For executing in batch, you'll need to create a shell script that setups the Java path so that you can execute it with a single command. The shell script does the heavy lifting. Here is an example of a started task JCL that uses BPXBATCH. As you can see the script is called and a single parameter is passed to the script (run):

```
//*
//BUZAGNT  PROC AGENT='/apps/ucd/v7.1.1/bin'
//BUZAGNT  EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,REGION=0M,TIME=NOLIMIT,
//            PARM='PGM &AGENT./agent run'
//STDOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//STDERR   DD SYSOUT=*
//*
//        PEND
//*
```